# How to define constructor with no arguments in android/java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run project and I am getting same error : Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<co.il.applicationmoran.PersonListAdapter> has no zero argument constructor.

I am trying to define default contructor without anysucsses , Can someone direct me how to do it ?

Thans . Here is my Class :

```
public class PersonListAdapter  extends  ArrayAdapter<person>
{
    private static String TAG = "PersonListAdapter";
    private Context mycontext;
    int myresource;


    public PersonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<person> objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mycontext = context;
        this.myresource=resource;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {
        String name = getItem(position).getName();
        String age=getItem(position).getAge();
        String sex=getItem(position).getSex();

        person person=new person(name,age,sex);
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mycontext);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(myresource, parent, false);

        TextView tvName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        TextView tvAge=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        TextView tvSex=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        tvName.setText(name);
        tvAge.setText(age);
        tvSex.setText(sex);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to `Override super(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<person> objects);` but I think it will cause you problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the zero argument constrctor , the problem is that you are trying to call your adapter with unvalid constructor , you have to pass context and an optional resource and the list of data used to fill the adapter's items .

Comment: Hi Can you specify more details ? or Example how to write it ? - Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
private Context mycontext;
int myresource;
 ArrayList<person> object=new ArrayList<person>();//missing line
  
  public PersonListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<person> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mycontext = context;
    this.myresource=resource;
    this.object=object;//missing this line in your code
}
```

Since your constructor has three parameter,you need to pass three argument wherever you are creating an instance of PersonListAdapter.